# ArcReader Publisher hung up in Exporting Raster Data

Tags: arcgis-publisher

We recently upgraded to ArcMap 10.7 from 10.4. I never had a problem publishing my .mxd and creating a data package. Now, same .mxd gets stuck in the exporting raster data phase of creating a data package.

Any ideas that may have caused this?